# Exporting movie from flash

Tags: flash, export, media

i made a animation in flash cc . in the mane time line ther is movie clips with animation inside and in each one ther is code
stop();
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(00);
and go to play the next movieclip until the next stop and play the next movie clip. when i export movie it's only export the movie of the mane time line what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add this on the last frame of each movie clip:

parent.goToNextFrame();

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I was looking for
I need a solution to video exporting that  ignoring the action script on the main time line and just keeps playing